# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n^4}{n^4} = 0$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} = 0$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n^4}{n^4} = 0$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} = 0$ where $S_n$ is the sum of $n$ iid RVs with mean zero.

**My question**

I'm having trouble understanding the final part of a proof for the strong LLN. See red box in screenshot below. I'm thinking the explanation is very quick and obvious but ugh I forgot most of HS Calculus. I think I found the proof for the converse [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362068/the-limit-of-the-product-of-two-convergent-sequences).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**My attempt**

If I can say that $\frac{S_n^4}{n^4} > \frac{S_n}{n}$ all the time then if the LHS goes to zero then so must the RHS. But this doesn't seem to be the case always, for example for $n=1$ I don't think I can always say that $X_1^4 > X_1$ since the only thing I know about the $X_i$'s are they have mean zero and they could take fractions as values.

---

**Book proof**

[image]

Comment: If $(s_n/n)^4\to 0$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a number $N(\epsilon)$ such that $\left| \frac{S_n}{n}\right|^4<\epsilon^4$ whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$.  Hence, for any $\epsilon$, $\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$.  Done.

Comment: Do you don't get why $(S_n/n)^4\to 0 \implies S_n/n\to 0$ ? It's because $\root{4}\of{x}$ is continuous, so $\root{4}\of{(S_n/n)^4}=|S_n/n|\to \root{4}\of{0}=0$. Finally, we get rid of absolute value (I think definition is the most straightforward for this)

Comment: @Jakobian yes... I know that implication is very clear to most people but unfortunately I'm having difficulty with it. =( As I mention in my post, I don't think that I can say that $\frac{S_n^4}{n^4} > \frac{S_n}{n}$ all the time which I feel is necessary to see that one implies the other

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks seeing it written out formally helps a lot! I thought I would have to prove that $\frac{S_n^4}{n^4} > \frac{S_n}{n}$ all the time... but maybe that isn't necessarily true? And in your proof I don't think that matters... is that the right thinking?

Comment: For big enough $n$, we would have $\frac{S_n^4}{n^4}\leq \big|\frac{S_n}{n}\big|$, actually. It's because $x^4\leq |x|$ for $|x|\leq 1$. And since $\frac{S_n}{n}$ goes to $0$, it needs to eventually be less than $1$

Comment: @Jakobian Hmm I think that's what confuses me. Because if $\frac{S_n^4}{n^4}\leq \big|\frac{S_n}{n}\big|$ then the LHS going to zero doesn't mean that the RHS goes to zero. The LHS is smaller than the RHS, so the LHS going to zero maybe doesn't "force" the RHS goes to zero? I saw Mark Viola's proof which makes sense but that seems to side step this thing I'm having confusion on.

Comment: Even if this inequality doesn't imply convergence of the other sequence, we can still show that it's convergent. In fact, we don't need that inequality

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks so much for your help!!!!! Per your proof, is it true always that if $f$ is a continuous function and $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence, then $f(\{x_n\})$ is a convergent sequence?

Comment: Not necessarily. $x_n=1/n$ and $f(x)=1/x$ is what comes to mind. Though, if it's a closed interval, it should always work. In fact, if $x_n\to x$, then it should be $f(x_n)\to f(x)$

Comment: @Jakobian Dude you are the man. Thanks so much for your patience. I wish I could give you points here. In lieu of that take this, #greencheck