# Limit of product and ratio of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n=L$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n=M$. Can we conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_nv_n=LM$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n/v_n=L/M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{u_n\cdot v_n}=L\cdot M$ but no, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\frac{u_n}{v_n}}=\frac{L}{M}$ is not always true. It only works if $M\neq 0$, you can find counter examples if $M=0$, take $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $v_n=\frac{1}{n}$, you have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{u_n}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{v_n}=0$ but $\frac{u_n}{v_n}=(-1)^n$ has no limit.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove by the definition of limit that the first one always holds for $L$ and $M$ finite.

The second one requires $M\neq 0$.

Refer to the related

- [The limit of the product of two convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2362068/505767)